# Stuck in tty. Can login in tty and run commands

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I am stuck in tty and

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

throws an error. What steps should i follow?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86152/discussion-on-question-by-rotsoc-stuck-in-tty-can-login-in-tty-and-run-commands).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the language which I did by running

> sudoedit /etc/default/locale

and editing these lines

```
LANG=en_US 
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
```

Then the error messages were in English. Trying different things, I realized that removing Python 3 caused the whole problem, broke apt and my system (don't do this!).

So I backed-up my files and reinstalled Ubuntu.